# Living machines. At which point can machines be considered a life form or organic?

Tags: technology, life, philosophy

I found this definition of life. **Life is a thing that can adapt to its environment, grow and replicate**. But mechanical, electrical, and electro-mechanical machines are never called alive.

People always dismiss the fact that machines can be living even though we ourselves are molecular machines.

**What requirements must a machine meet to be considered alive?**

For example, if an automated factory builds other factories is it alive? Or if some yet to be invested nano-machine self-replicated would they be considered a life form?

Extra points for a solid argument for why or why not something like this considered a life form.

To be clear, this doesn't entail intelligence, self-awareness or any of that.  Bacteria are alive and don't possess anything recognized as intelligence.

Comment: Shouting won't make your question any good...

Comment: This is a very good question, but will be opinion-based, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hmmm. What life is has been a prominent philosophical problem from the beginning of philosophy, deep in the caves where our ancestors the cavemen expressed their artistic inclinations. What makes you think that there is a definitive answer which can be found on an internet site? As a gentle introduction I recommend [Erwin Schrödinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erwin_Schr%C3%B6dinger)'s (he the cat man!) 1944 booklet, [*What is Life?*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_Is_Life%3F); as luck would have it, it is [freely available](http://www.whatislife.ie/downloads/What-is-Life.pdf) online.

Comment: Sadly, there is no way not to make this an opinion based question.  Different philosophers and biologists throughout history have defined life differently meaning there is no one answer.  In general, things that are alive are things that "have the same properties as other things we consider to be alive", but even just here on Earth, there is such a smooth gradient between life and not-life that any hard line you use to says "you're alive now" is purely artificial.

Comment: I don't concur that this query is opinion based. Whether theologians or philosophers or even us ordinary folk agree with it or not, the OP laid out a clear and concise definition of life. That reduces the "opinion based" factor to well within tolerable limits. The question does need to be cleaned of its snarkiness, but otherwise ought to be reopened.

Comment: However, you really should pick which question of the two you're asking you actually want to focus on!

Comment: I would like to sincerely apologize to everyone who interpreted my question as snotty and snarky as well as the shouting part (I didn't even realize that was shouting). This is mostly due to my questions often getting closed so I wanted to make sure this question gets answered. The community has been pretty ruthless with me so thank you for understanding.

Comment: Relevent https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10479/changing-the-definition-of-life. some background research no you part will go a long way to make this an acceptable question.

Comment: As others have said, this question is philosophical and as such doesn't have a distinct right answer. It's opinion based. Great question either way though. This question might go well over at https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: To be honest, friend: you're new here, so please don't take question closure in such a personal way. You've only asked three questions! Two of them are currently open. Closing a question simply means that there is some problem with it that makes it a poor fit for the Stack Exchange model. If you haven't already, I'd invite you to take a look at the [tour] and the [help] so you can get a better understanding how SE works. WB.SE is not for open ended questions. It's really designed in such a way that you, the geopoet, can ask a laser-focused query and get on point responses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've answered your own question. You've defined life as follows: **Life is a thing that can adapt to its environment, grow and replicate.** Thus, we have three criteria:

- Does it adapt to its environment?
- Does it grow?
- Does it replicate?

And thus anything which fulfills that criteria is alive. But then you ask when a machine can be considered biologically alive, that's a different set of criteria - typically these seven: Homeostasis, Organization, Metabolism, Growth, Adaption, Response, and Reproduction. Of course, there are arguments over how exactly to place these definitions, but that's the general overview. So a production factory doesn't fulfill these quotas - hence, it's not 'alive' by these definitions. A self-replicating nanomachine, like the Gray Goo scenario, would meet all your requirements and most of the biological requirements, so by your definition it can be 'alive.' We might say that it's 'metal-based life'.

And, if you don't want to get into philosophy about consciousness or souls or anything of that nature, that's the best you can get - a simple list of conditions to check off.

Comment: I think it might be worth explaining what those seven requirements for biological life might mean in the context of a machine - would a factory that has an integrated AC system with a thermostat meet the requirement of homeostasis?

Answer (score 3):

There is no established science here.

As we look deeper into this question, we can come up with a number of borderline theoretical examples which can be decided both ways.

Traditionally life is defined as organic, protein and DNA-based. But this is a pretty narrow definition, and most people agree that this definition is likely too narrow. To comply with this definition, machine must resemble existing living organisms very much, be susceptible to mutations and branching into different species.

The next popular and closely related question is "Are viruses alive?" Viruses lack traditional cell structure and can't function without reliance on living cells. If we decide this question affirmatively, then the possible range of "living machines" would expand dramatically. We can even construct new ones today. A "sister question" is "Are [Prions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prion) alive?", and affirmative answer here can further expand the "machine domain".

When we move out of biological domain, the question becomes even more murky. For example, is [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) alive? If yes, then bingo, we have essentially solved the enigma of life. If not, then what algorithm can satisfy the requirement?

For physical machines, implementation is of course more difficult than "game of life", but philosophical question remains the same. Self-replication can be defined relatively easy, but adaptability is not quite so. What is the range of condition that living organism should be able to adapt to in order to be called "live"?

We may throw in another condition for life to be called life - the environment the organism is living should be natural - at least in the sense that it does not require any maintenance from an intelligent force. This would force the range of "living machines" to be more narrow, but we still can have a lot of variations.

Overall, this question can not be answered without deciding on a number of definitions.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the paradigm.
Currently, artificial intelligence is considered in a social context.

what criteria must he meet?

In biological, social etc criteria may vary.

I think that the basic criterion that separates the technological peculiarity from the human race is the ability to feel emotions and empathy.

Other interesting issues are, if the machine is considered living, what its legal personality will look like - and then social perception by people.

Halfhawed answer very well:

quite precisely - the ability to adapt, propagate, develop, create a community based on given principles.

Returning to the concept of the feelings of the machine as a determining factor as living - perhaps it is unnecessary for machines. They can develop without emotions, and yet create high-class cultures or communities.

This is an interesting topic to consider :)